# Zend require_once error in apache2 error.log

Tags: zend-framework, googlebot

I have noticed some problems in apache2 error.log. My server receive request from ip address 66.249.72.182,66.249.78.76 (googlebot???), and in /var/log/apache2/error.log i have records:

```
[error] [client 66.249.72.182] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening  required 'Zend/Cloud/Infrastructure/Instance.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/xxxx.com/library/Zend/Cloud/Infrastructure/InstanceList.php on line 10
[error] [client 66.249.72.182] PHP Warning:  require_once(Zend/Gdata/Extension.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/xxxx.com/library/Zend/Gdata/Photos/Extension/PhotoId.php on line 27
[error] [client 66.249.78.76] PHP Warning:  require_once(Zend/Gdata/Extension.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/xxxx.com/library/Zend/Gdata/Photos/Extension/NumPhotosRemaining.php on line 27
```

and etc.  I think request to all file in /library/Zend/*. I don't understand how. In .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

in index.php:

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
   realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
   get_include_path(),
)));
```

I don't understand where is problem. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your access.log to see how exactly they were accessed. Maybe that's some virtual host which makes the library path accessible to the public. Obviously, your library and application directories should reside one level up relative to the DocumentRoot and directory indexes should be turned off.

Comment: Mr.Key,thank for answer! `tail -100f access.log | grep 66.249.78.76` - return empty. `tail -100f error.log | grep 66.249.78.76` - return 100 last error, sample `[error] [client 66.249.72.182] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening  required 'Zend/Cloud/Infrastructure/Instance.php` (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/xxxx.com/library/Zend/Cloud/Infrastructure/InstanceList.php on line 10

Comment: The problem is solved. One of virtual host was making the path accessible.